# How to use an ignore case statement for inputs

Tags: java, case, do-while, void, ignore-case

How do you ignore the upper and lower case. I have made a display menu, and when I enter the lower case letter the correct output occurred, but when i enter an upper case letter it carries on with the while statement. I know i have to use an ignoreCase statement but I don't know how. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Aaa {
    AQAConsole2016 console = new AQAConsole2016();
    Random random = new Random();
    int boardSize;
    boolean moveIsValid;

    char [][] board;
    int move;
    char choice;
    String playerName="Human";
    String player2="Computer";
    boolean exit=false;
    public Aaa() {

        boardSize = 6;

        do {
            displayMenu();
            choice = getMenuChoice(playerName);
            switch (choice) {
            case 'p' : playGame(playerName, boardSize);
            break;
            case 'e' : playerName = getPlayersName();
            break;
            case 'c' : boardSize = changeBoardSize();
            break;
            case 'm' : Multiplayer( boardSize,playerName,player2);
            break;
            case 'r' :readBoard(board,boardSize);
            break;
            case 'q' : Quit();


            }
        }while (choice!='p'||choice!='e'||choice!='c'||choice!='m'||choice!='r'||choice!='q');
    }
    void Quit(){
        while (choice=='q'){
            exit=true;
        }
```

Comment: so you need/want that the user menu reacts to p and P for example??

Comment: yes, when the user types in a p or P,  r or R etc

Answer (score 2):

Just use [Character#toLowerCase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29) for this.

```
choice = Character.toLowerCase(getMenuChoice(playerName));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Character to lowercase [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toLowerCase%28char%29)

## Example:

```
     displayMenu();
     choice = Character.toLowerCase(getMenuChoice(playerName));
     switch (choice) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to use `toLowerCase()` function.

```
displayMenu();
choice = Character.toLowerCase(getMenuChoice(playerName));
```